# Why is $\vec E \cdot \vec n = ||\vec E||$ for a vector field $\vec E$ and a unit vector $\vec n$?

Tags: vectors, vector-fields

Apparently $\vec E \cdot \vec n = ||\vec E||$ . I can't see why this is through the math...the only thing we know about $\vec n$ is that its magnitude is $1$.

I realize we could use the formula $\vec E \cdot \vec n =||\vec E||||\vec n||\cos \theta$ here, but I'm reaching a contradiction through the other definition of dot product based on components:

If for example, $\vec n = \hat i  +0\hat j$ and $\vec E = 3\hat i + 3\hat j$, then $\vec E \cdot \vec n = 3 \neq ||\vec E|| $

Comment: As you pointed out, the formula as stated clearly does not hold. It only does so if $\vec{n}$ lies in the same direction as $\vec{E}$.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Thank you! So can we only calculate dot products based off components when the two vectors we're calculating the dot product of are pointing in the same direction?

Comment: Well, calculating $\vec{E} \cdot \vec{n}$ always gives you the component of $\vec{E}$ in the direction of $\vec{n}$, if that is what you are asking?

Comment: @JamesRonald Not quite. You can still calculate the dot product even if $\vec E$ and $\vec n$ are not in the same direction, but what Alex was saying is that this dot product simply will no longer be equal to $||\vec E||$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot product $\vec E \cdot \vec n$ is **not** in general equal to $||\vec E||$, the length of $\vec E$.

Remember, the dot product of two vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$  represents $$||\vec A|| \times ||\text{proj}_{\vec A}{\vec B}|| $$
where $\text{proj}_{\vec A}{\vec B}$ is the projection of $\vec B$ onto $\vec A$.
The above expression equals
$$||\vec B|| \times ||\text{proj}_{\vec B}{\vec A}|| $$
which equals
$$(||\vec A||)(||\vec B||)\cos(\theta)$$
and where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec A$ and $\vec B$.

What this means in plain English is that to get the dot product of two vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$, you project one onto the other (say, $A$ onto $B$, which we write as $\text{proj}_{\vec B}{\vec A}$) , then multiply the length of the projection by the length of the other remaining vector (in this case, $\vec B$).

Now we can apply this to your specific problem. Looking at the last equation, we see that if $\vec n$ is a unit vector (that is, $||\vec n||=1$), then
$$\vec E \cdot \vec n = (||\vec E||)(||\vec n||)\cos(\theta) = (||\vec E||)\cos(\theta).$$
This is equal to $||\vec E||$ precisely when $\cos(\theta)=1$, which is true precisely if $\theta$ is a multiple of $2\pi$, that is, when $\vec E$ and $\vec n$ point in the same direction.

On the other hand, if $\theta$ is not a multiple of $2\pi$, then $\cos(\theta) \ne 1$, so then $(||\vec E||)\cos(\theta) \ne ||\vec E||$.

Hope this helps, feel free to comment if you'd like me to elaborate.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough response! This helped with a lot more than just my question, and everything is very clear so no questions on my part. Sincere thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your apparent observation is incorrect as you yourself correct it later: $\vec E \cdot \vec n = ||\vec E|| \cdot ||\vec n || \cdot cos(\theta)$

You have a mistake by omitting the $cos(\theta)$.